# How to search records based on date range for other matching data

Tags: query, subquery

I have below records in table

```
APP_No Stage Start_Date End_Date 
A123   L1    01-01-19 02-01-19 
A123   D1    01-03-19 05-03-19 
A345   L1    01-01-19 02-01-19 
A345   D1    01-03-19 05-03-19
```

I want to search records for stage D1 for the month of `Mar19` but this should include data for L1 stage also, since related app ID fall between same Mar19 date range. 

I have used condition in where clause as : `trunc(Col_Name) BETWEEN trunc (sysdate, 'mm')/current month/ AND SYSDATE`

Please help with solution

Comment: Dates are tricky and frequently non-standard. Please indicate your server. You can look at my profile for several articles about how to ask questions. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try ans use `EXISTS` to get all records where another (or the same for that matter) exists with the same app ID, a stage of `'D1'` and the start date or the end date in march.

Assuming you're on Oralce, this could look like this:

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.app_no = t1.app_no
                                  AND stage = 'D1'
                                  AND (t2.start_date >= to_date('2019-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                                       AND t2.start_date < to_date('2019-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                                        OR t2.end_date >= to_date('2019-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                                           AND t2.end_date < to_date('2019-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));
```